Calculating force and pressure from karate board breaking
I am working on a project involving breaking boards with kicks and punches. I want to address the following questions:

Do the bottom boards always break first?
According to Pascal's principle, the smaller the surface area, the more the force is focused. The elephant has just as much pressure on its foot as a ballerina does. So, how much force is in the area the foot contacts the board in a kick?
The more experienced you become, the more efficient you are at focusing energy. Do more experienced karateka have smaller surface areas that actually contact the boards in their hits?

I will use slow motion videos to analyse what strikes the boards and which ones hit the wood first.

Will I have to calculate the energy and mechanics of the limbs that do the strike? (Eg. will I have to record and calculate the energy and leverage of the way my leg kicks the wood?)

I will put ink on my foot before kicking the boards and measure the mark of the area that contacted the wood. I want to use computer software to measure the precise surface area of the contact surface with a photo.

Do you know what kind of computer program that would be?

How do you suggest I calculate the final velocity of the strike?
I know that frame by frame analysis are often used to calculate velocity in sports. However, the distance and time duration of the strike may be too short to accurately calculate final velocity.



Related.

Realted - Resulting force when bending plywood
